# Can you replace a dead alchemical familiar?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, familiars

Let's say Bob, an Alchemist, took the [Alchemical Familiar](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=92) class feat.
Now let's say this familiar gets killed.

Is there a way for Bob to get his familiar back?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Yes

> [If your familiar dies, you can spend a week of downtime to replace it at no cost.](https://2e.aonprd.com/Familiars.aspx)

Comment: ...or at your next daily preparation, if you're a Witch (but you're without your spellbook in the interim, which really sucks).